# Ubuntu Budgie: Can't use FN keys on login screen

Tags: 18.04, laptop, asus, login-screen, ubuntu-budgie

I can't use <kbd>FN</kbd> keys on the login screen in Ubuntu Budgie 18.04.

This means I can't change the brightness or volume.

How can I fix this?

edit:I can use <kbd>FN</kbd> after login screen.
my device is asus vivobook 510 12gb ram nvida 940mx intel corei7

Comment: Please clearly express a question in the header of your topic, and elaborate clearly in the body of your message, providing the most relevant information possible.

Comment: Perhaps you need to specify which function key or keys do not work as you expect.

Comment: So the Fn keys work OK after login? You might consider reporting a bug about this. Your hardware details (make and model of the device) might be useful info. You can [edit] your question to add information.